# Which PHP extension should I use for my DB wrapper

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I'm building a database wrapper for my own use and I can't decide which PHP extension I should use, PDO or MySQLi.

I'm only planning to use MySQL so I don't care about the support for other adapters with PDO. I've read a lot that PDO is becoming a 'standard' with PHP and perhaps I should use that? Then I think it's 'too much' because I only have the use of the MySQL adapter. But is MySQLi going to stick around and be further developed?

I know there's a lot of threads dealing with the difference between the both but I didn't find anyone answering my question.

P.S Have patience with the language, I'm an åäö (Swedish) kind of guy :)

Comment: What is your wrapper supposed to do? I.e. what do you want to "wrap"?

Comment: Perhaps wrapper is the wrong word, I will use it to perform different database operations like SELECT, INSERT etc.

Answer (score 1):

Although PDO is supposed to be/become The Standard, it is far from perfect.
I use PDO daily and it sports quite some bugs (most which you can quite easily workaround, but still).

If it is of any measure look at the reported [bugs](http://bugs.php.net) for pdo and mysqli: 112 and 41 respectively.

My **subjective** point of view is: despite the above, go with PDO. I find it very usable.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest if you are going for large scale applications go for PDO, but for small applications go for MySqli because if you get any problems it will be easier to debug than PDO as you are not going to use any other database adapter